# Magento 2. How do Tax Rules apply? (Priority)

Tags: magento2, taxes

I'm looking at the [docs](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/tax/tax-rules.html) on tax rules and I'm a little fuzzy in regards to the priority field and how rules apply.

> If two tax rules with the same priority apply, the taxes are added together. If two taxes with different priority settings apply, the taxes are compounded.

What does **compounded** mean in practice? An example would be great.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Compounded** means that the value of the second tax is calculated based on the total resulted after applying the first tax, see an example bellow ([resource](https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/tax/tax-compound.html)):

[image]